# Finitely generated projective = finitely presented flat over a noncommutative Noetherian ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a possibly noncommutative left Noetherian ring and $M$ an $R$-module. I am looking for a reference or a proof for the following fact: $M$ is finitely generated and projective if and only if it is finitely presented and flat. (I am not interested in references that treat only the commutative case.)

Comment: The proof given in http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058Q works for the general case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This holds over any ring, noetherian or not. See Bourbaki *Algebra* X, §1, no. 5.

Answer (score 5):

You can find a detailed proof in Chapter 2, §4D of T. Y. Lam, *Lectures on modules and rings,* Grad. Texts in Math., Springer, 1999. (More precisely, it follows from Proposition 4.26 a), Proposition 4.29 and Theorem 4.30.)

Answer (score 1):

An even more general statement is proved in Borceux and Quinteiro's [*Enriched Accessible Categories*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700021900).

They show that the Cauchy completion of a small $\mathcal{V}$-category $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to the category of $\mathcal{V}$-finitely presentable $\mathcal{V}$-flat presheaves on $\mathcal{C}$.

To get the result you ask about, take $\mathcal{V} = \textbf{Ab}$ (the category of abelian groups) and treat a ring $R$ as a $\mathcal{V}$-enriched category $\mathcal{R}$ with one object. Then use the [fact](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/tiny-objects/) that the Cauchy completion of $\mathcal{R}$ is the category of finitely generated projective $R$ modules.